# Virus warning in Bitcoin [cash] ABC client?

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, bitcoin-cash, wallet-security, virus

I tried to download Bitcoin cash ABC wallet from bitcoincash official site.

If I download zip to my computer and upload it to VirusTotal site, it says 11/62 positives.
If I go to VirusTotal site and enter the zip URL to be scanned it says it is clean.
<del>SHA-256 sum is also different.</del>

Is this normal ? 
Maybe someone else can test ? :/

https://download.bitcoinabc.org/0.17.2/win/bitcoin-abc-0.17.2-win64.zip

edit: the SHA256 is the same, I initially thought it was different, maybe I compared too many at once, the main issue (warnings) remains.

[image: clean, from url]
[image: not clean, from downloaded zip]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's very usual and expected.

It is not surprising to have Bitcoin-related code in Bitcoin Core(-forks), but the malware analyzers don't understand the purpose of Bitcoin code.

Here's a real software with a Bitcoin miner (utorrent 3.4.2): https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/0e7e8526e8c4ab3c3dc938b1bb042bda07f464390a919c7f3f30caadec156549/detection

The same happens for Bitcoin Core:
[image]